# How to identify and bring cell from column X that contains all values from row Y?

Tags: vba, excel

I´ve a long (+50k items) master file that contains names and addresses; all in one column:

> John Doe, TX - Houston
>
> Richard Gonzalez, TX - Lipscomb
>
> .......

Now, I´ve a much shorter list of people I need to find there.
I´ve name in column B, surname in C, state in D, county in E, but for many of them, I´ve partial information (mainly no address), and I need to find if they´re in my master file or not.
It may be that I´ve:

> John --------------- Doe -----------------  TX

But no County, and there may be multiple matches in my master file so I need to bring them all.

I tried this formula, which gives me true if all the values I´m looking for are indeed in a specific cell:

```
=+AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1,A:A)),(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C1,A:A))),(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D1,A:A))),(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(E1,A:A))))
```

That was a great advance, as now I know which ones I´ll be able to find, but I would like the formula to tell me in which cells can I find them, and bring me those cell contents next to my search if possible too.

How should I do this?
Any help or hint would be much appreciated!

Edit:

[image]

Comment: could you please provide us the code you've written so far? many thx.

Comment: The formula I used is up here, and it tells me when the conditions are true, but I dont  know for which  cells that happens.

Comment: could you please upload a screenshot of the formula execution it will make  it easier for us.
Example: cell b1 = alphabet, cell c1 =search("b"; b1) -> result is 6 -> on the 6th position the first match occured. `isnumber(search(..))` is always true because search returns a number. what i expierenced so far, I assume that the search values of B1, C1 and D1 are matched in A1

Comment: I'll edit when I get back home today. Thanks psich!

Comment: @psychicebola, please see the screenshot. Thanks for your help!

Comment: search is not sufficient for your needs because it searches the row col A in which the function is placed -> if the function is in `F3` it searches the string within cell `A3` and not the range you specified `A:A`

Comment: all i could do for you so far is as follows: use this function to retrieve the cell values of A matching the searches of B to D
`=cells("address";INDEX(A:A;match("*"&b2&"*";A:A;0);1))`